# list files and folders of the root partion

Tags: disk-usage

My root partion is full and I am going to clean up it a bit. But I have confused with partitions and folders. I.e. deleting unneeded files in home directory doesn't increase / partition size but if I list it, system shows another picture.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,7M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda8        19G   17G  468M  98% /
tmpfs           7,8G  722M  7,1G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      140M  140M     0 100% /snap/slack/24
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop4      129M  129M     0 100% /snap/sweethome3d-homedesign/9
/dev/loop5      145M  145M     0 100% /snap/slack/25
/dev/loop6       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/sda2        96M   81M   16M  84% /boot/efi
/dev/sda10       28G  6,1G   21G  23% /home
tmpfs           1,6G   64K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop7       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/sda7        15G   14G  1,7G  89% /media/alex/SASHA
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:~$ df /root/
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8       19091584 17619740    478976  98% /
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:~$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8       19091584 17619740    478976  98% /
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:~$ cd /mnt/
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:/mnt$ ls
bacula-console.conf.ucftmp-iatbDRUGJi  bacula-director.conf.ucftmp-iiJ0w1gZEH  bacula-fd.conf.ucftmp-3B2f7qUh3a  bacula-sd.conf.ucftmp-nBESqCvQnZ  bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old
alex@alex-HP-ProBook-430-G4:/mnt$
```

Its not clear what takes 17G of /dev/sda8 partition and what folders belong to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First standard cleanup & update.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Autoclean cleans up the downloaded archives (.gz or .tar) files used to install things. Autoremove cleans libraries that are no longer needed.

Then we can start search for large folders with du.

Size of apt caches (often an issue)

```
sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives

find ~/.cache/ -depth -type f -atime +365
```

Delete all old cache entries, you can change to any number of days.

```
find ~/.cache/ -type f -atime +365 -delete
```

I also delete the older logs if no issues.

```
find /var/log/ -type f -atime +10  -name *.gz* -print -exec rm {} \;
```

houseclean journalctl over 10 days

```
journalctl --vacuum-time=10d
```

Then if not typical cache we can search.
cd / or cd /home

```
sudo du -hc --max-depth=1
```

Or and then for largest folder change from / to that folder - /var as an example and keep drilling down:

```
sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null
sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 /var 2> /dev/null
```

I once forgot to mount my backup and it put the entire thing into /. I just barely had room, so system did not crash but root was almost full.

You also can check for large folders & files:

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | grep '[0-9]G\>'   # folders larger than 1GB
sudo find / -name '*' -size +1G    # files larger than 1GB
```

or install ncdu and drill down from / (q to quit):

```
sudo ncdu /
```

Answer (score 1):

Disk partition sizes are normally fixed, so it doesn't really matter how many files are in there - the size will remain the same until you manually change it.

To see what's in /dev/sda8 you can run:

```
sudo sfdisk -l | grep ^/dev
```

and the **last 2 columns** will show the size and type (what's contained) in the partition.