# Move space from /home to / (root) in Ubuntu 20 without bootable pendrive/cd in SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I want to move 30 GB space from home to root.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   11M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p7   19G   14G  3.6G  80% /
tmpfs           7.8G  158M  7.6G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop2       16M   16M     0 100% /snap/easy-openvpn-server/64
/dev/loop5      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop3      162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop4       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop6      2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop0       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop7       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop8      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop9      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop10      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/simplescreenrecorder/1
/dev/loop11     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop12      68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/nvme0n1p8  147G  1.6G  138G   2% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  356M  116M  241M  33% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   24K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

My home partition is currently 147 GB and root is 19 GB. I want to make it 117 GB + 49 GB.
I tried sommands given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213245/increase-root-partition-by-reducing-home replacing `/dev/mapper...` with `/dev/nvme...` from console login. But the `fsck` command is giving error `Cannot continue, aborting.`

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you really using /home partition? You have almost nothing in it and lots in / (root)? Your link is for LVM (volumes) which use LVM tools to resize. You should just need gparted from live installer.  Post your fstab above. `cat /etc/fstab` Have you checked what is using a lot of / ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: @oldfred I purposefully cleared the home so that its easier to resize. Most of the space in / was taken up by /usr/lib  It would have been a lot easier with live pendrive but I wanted to do it without any bootable external device. 
Although, I have successfully achieved it now. I freed 117 GB of home from right side, mounted /home to this new free space, then freed the original home (19 GB size) and finally merged root with this new free space.