# Dual boot ubuntu installation partitions not exhibiting expected file storage behavior

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I examined many different threads within here and on the regular Ubuntu forums with respect to dual booting Ubuntu (Studio) 20.04. What I thought would be my 28G boot partition turns out to be my entire filesystem partition, aside from my home directory (and subdirectories). Looking at Gparted, this makes sense now, though now this / partition is full.

[image]

What would be the best long term solution to this situation?

Could a short term solution be to remove the 32G partition right next to it, and have the / partition expand into that space? There's really nothing in there that I can access, from Thunar it shows "Lost&Found" with an X through it.

Comment: So you don't care to delete `nvme0n1p8`? Go for it. Long term solution: IMO!!, would be to backup your files, wipe p7 p8 p9 and reinstall if you don't mind to do so, this time being generous with the system partition, or not have /home partition at all.

Comment: What is filling your / (root)? I have all data in a separate data partition and / is about 9GB with Kubuntu 20.04 & no snaps.  to see details cd / or cd /home
`sudo du -hc --max-depth=1` or install ncdu and change to / and `sudo ncdu`, then drill down on larger folders. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327