# Default space of Ubuntu

Tags: files

I am new to Ubuntu and am currently dual booting windows and Ubuntu. I want to increase the size of the ubuntu file system, and I found that this is possible by using GParted.

But I am curious about something. When I installed Ubuntu the default size of the file system partition was 80G. After installation I only downloaded chrome and flutter but I saw that the file system was almost full(76.4/80G). Is it normal that Ubuntu itself takes up so much file space, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Either something went wrong, or you have a lot of personal files. My Ubuntu 20.04 installation is 18GB that includes the OS, all downloaded applications, their config files, and their caches. My personal files do not count in that.

Comment: Flutter can have a lot of dependencies depending on what you installed and how you did it. You can begin tracking down where all your storage space has gone using a tool like "Disk Usage Analyzer", which will give you a graphical overview of large directories.

Comment: Try ncdu & housecleaning. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: You didn't specify what release of Ubuntu you're using, however if you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements you'll note 25GB is the recommended minimum disk size for Ubuntu Desktop (since Ubuntu 17.10) so using that space so quickly is normal