# why is my 50 GB root partition getting full?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, root

So, I just realized that my root partition which is 50 GB, only has 6 GB free space.

p.s: I have separate root and home partition, my home partition is 180 GB
and I have a 1TB HDD drive too which I use for my most of my big files.

Should I do anything? like resizing or anything(just guessing),
or it has enough space?

edit: I've never saved personal files on my root partition

second edit: So I did a scan on the partition and here's how is my root partition that big

I have 26 GB on /var (21 GB on /var/lib, 20 GB of it on /var/lib/snapd and on snapd, 14 GB is on /var/lib/snapd/snapshots) and 5 GB on /var/log)

and 14.1 GB on /usr (8 gb on /usr/lib and 4 gb on /usr/share)

these were the big files

Comment: Find out what is taking so much disk space. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem

Comment: In all my years of using Ubuntu my root never exceeded 20Gb. You seem to have personal(?) data on / and outside of /home so the free space will increase. Find the cuprit and fix the issue. Do start out with /var/log/ maybe it has a very large log file with errors you neglected ;-)

Comment: We can't know as we have no details. You've mentioned two partitions (/ & /home) but mention only one size (50GB so we don't know if that's 50GB each, combined or a combination).  Your question as provided is vague & unclear.  My system has 26GB & 27GB for / & /home & I live with it and have done so for years (7 *release-upgrades* so far) and 6GB free space to me seems huge! & I'm jealous) but I spend a lot of time ensuring my system keeps running (ie. high maintenance due to my lack of disk space...) so it's a decision of time vs space (& of course how we use our systems; I wish I had 32GB)

Comment: In addition to pLumo's link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: @oldfred that is two times same link ;-)

Comment: So what takes up so much space in `/var/lib`? Might be `/var/lib/snapd/`? That is where the snap packages are installed to.... If so , check output of `du -h /var/lib/snapd/snaps/*`...

Comment: @pLumo yes you are right, there's 20GB in snapd. I checked the output of that command, its a total of 2.3 GB of 100,200, <100  files

,also, 14GB of snapd is in snapshots and 3GB in cache

Comment: So. Remove some `snap` packages you don't need anymore. Also, you have snapshots of `snap` packages. Automatic snapshots is disabled in Ubuntu. Either you made snapshots manually or you enabled the feature. Check with `snap saved`.

Comment: @pLumo auto snapshots or something, but anyway turned it off in case it have been on.  just a question, is there any special command to delete snapshots? and one another last thing, the total of snap saved is 8GB, so after I clean it, root will be something around 35GB, is that a normal amount?

Comment: It is not  possible to say if 35GB is a normal amount or not. My root is 13 GB, but I don't have wine, no docker, my virtual machines folder is symlinked to another disk, I periodically purge old kernels, I completely purged snaps... According to the apps you use your 35 GB may be normal as my 13 GB are.

Comment: big thanks everybody, problem solved, I guess I just edit the post title to a proper one and mark as duplicate

Comment: just forgot to add answer before marking az duplicate, for anyone visiting new, The problem was mostly my `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots` , it seemed like i had turned on automatic snapshots or I made them manually. anyway, i deleted them with `snap forget` command.