# How to increase the partition size of root disk in ubuntu linux?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted, root, unallocated

I have some 55 Gb unallocated space in my disk and I want to give it to root but I can't resize the root disk. I even tried to do it by bootable live USB but inside Gparted, the root partition doesn't show available 55 GB space.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: I really don't think you can adjust the size of the root partition. However, you can probably adjust it in a dual-boot system, like Ubuntu and Windows 10. Why do you want to adjust the size of the root partition? It seems pointless, and could be fatal. I would not recommend trying it.

Comment: Why is / (root) so large? You may want to houseclean or check that something that should be in /home is not in / or one of your backups was written into / when it should have written to external drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: ...or you created the /home partition, and now mount it, but never cleaned out the root's /home... files, so they still take up room, but are hidden from view. du -s /* 2>/dev/null should give you sizes on all the top level directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to increase the size of your root partition, the empty space must be contiguous (right next to) the root partition.

To do this, you will need to boot from a USB, then using `gparted`

1. Move the swap partition as far to the right as possible
2. Move the /home partition as far to the right as possible
3. Expand the root partition

Please not that this is not a fast set of operations, and it is not without risk.  Backup your data before you undertake this operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how can I move or change partition path name bcoz I think it’s in serial

Comment: I don't believe that you need to, or should, attempt to change the partition path name.  In all three steps above, I mention moving the partition, or expanding that partition.  No renaming.  For instructions on how to move a partition, please see [https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions)