# Can't figure out why is my root is running out of space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, disk, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu on dual boot with my Windows. I allocated a 80GB of my nvdme 1TB SSD for a partition that I installed Linux on.

Then I launched my PC with a USB that got the ISO of Ubuntu on and got to the installation screen of ubunutu.

I have installed Ubuntu and gave for the root partition 20GB and for the home partition the rest of the total 80GB (60~GB).

For about 3 months I worked perfecatlly but I started to get warning about running out of space.

Why would it happen? I have 80GB!

Maybe it's because I install everything on my root directory instead on the home directory? I thought that all my files and everything is installed on my home directory.

I have nothing on my PC. just C files and project, a 80MB folder.
That's it. I installed FireFox and Discord, and few other programs for coding (CLion, PyCharm, VSC). Nothing else.

What can it be?

Pictures of me writing `df -h` after `cd /`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have only 19GB in root, the rest of free space doesn't matter. It seems you have installed a lot of snaps and snaps take a lot more space than the traditional .deb files. So, perhaps, a 30-50GB root would be more sensible.

Comment: Can I reboot my PC and launch Windows and enter partition manager, and somehow resize the root partition and make it bigger without harming or damaging the current files on the root?

Comment: You need to find out what is taking up space in your `/var` and `/usr` dirs. Try giving the output of `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var | sort -hr` and `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /usr | sort -hr` to further see what's taking up space.

Comment: No, you can't. You may do that on a Ubuntu live session with Gparted but is always a risky operation so you must have backups. Actually it's a set of complex operations: First shrink /home, then move it all the way to the right and finally expand / to the now unallocated space at its right.

Comment: You are handling with the consequences of previous decisions you made to dual-boot (instead of VM), to over-partition, and to separate your /home into a different partition. Rather than fix the specific problem (lots of snaps, maybe a runaway logfile), decide if your original plan still works now that you have some experience with the workflow. If you want to make changes, this is a good time.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have added screenshots of the outputs of the commands you told me to execute

Comment: @user535733 I actually had no idea, I just read a guide of "how to install dual boot ubuntu" because I wanted to work on Linux and on Ubuntu. I'm glad I did it and I won't get back to other OS anymore. I prefer dual boot over VM because of that exact reason, I want the full experience of Ubuntu. The question is what can I do now? How can I make the /root directory bigger?

Comment: You can use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions and then use gparted from live installer to resize Linux partitions. I do not use snaps, houseclean aggressively and my Kubuntu install uses about 9GB in a 30GB root. But I have lots of data in larger data partitions.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-p

Comment: Now do the same with `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib | sort -hr` and `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /usr/lib | sort -hr`. Looks like you "lib" directories are rather large, which could well be snaps as others have suggested. 2 GB for logs are also big, but maybe not as critical as it could be.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Added screenshots of the commands that you told me.

Comment: @oldfred You're a life saver! I did every command you suggest on in the link you provided and I freed 4.5GB. But it just saves me for a limited time till i'll fill it up again. I want to resize my partition somehow to be bigger than the 20GB I allocated it when I first installed Ubuntu. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Ok in `var` it's snaps, and in `usr` it's modules and libraries. I guess what others have said are true, you probably need more space for `/root` if you want to use Ubuntu like you do.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Can I somehow uninstall those snaps? I don't even know what are they. I think that parts of my downloaded programs are "snaps" because I read somewhere that for example, PyCharm is updated to a newer version on Snaps but not on Ubuntu Store, so I preferred to download it from as a snap.

Comment: @ArturMeinild So here we roll back to the original question - is there any way to add more space for `/root` without harming the current files? I have dual boot so I can enter somehow the Window's partition manager

Comment: I can't really add anything to that - it's a risky procedure to resize partitions, and I haven't done it myself.

Comment: It’s not difficult to resize Linux partitions. You need a live environment, the Ubuntu installer is perfect, you choose “Try Ubuntu” and get a desktop with the GParted app available. You can then shrink home and expand root. Make sure you have backups of anything you cannot afford to lose. Alternatively backup your home data, delete your home partition and expand root to the max. Restore your home data.