# I have 336GB Data as a total, but my SSD is full!

Tags: disk-usage, 21.10

Why do I have only 336 GB of data, but the SSD is showing full?
I tried:

```
du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
```

The result is:

```
336G    /
336G    total
```

using Ubuntu 21.10
Thanks.

[image: SSD]

[image: ncdu]

It's weird when I check the System monitor it looks like:
[image: System monitor]

Gparted:
[image]

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows that the volume is 1TB in capacity and there is only 26GB remaining.

Comment: Try `ncdu` to locate big files.

Comment: Yes, and I have only 336GB data.

Comment: Maybe some files you don't have permission to. Try `sudo ncdu /`

Comment: @pLumo the above screen shot is sudo ncdu

Comment: Do you run Docker containers that perform a large number of write operations?

Comment: @matigo no, I have no Docker running at the moment.

Comment: Have you housecleaned, particularly trash? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: Even the cleanup, didn't work. But check the system monitor screenshot I added lately!!!

Comment: Start gparted and look at the partitions. Possibly you have 1TByte SSD, but the root partition is much smaller (358GByte).

Comment: Yes its @MikroPower, any idea how I extend the root partition to 1tb without deleting my laptop?

Comment: With a Life-USB-Stick (because you have to unmount the partition) and there is always gparted installed, so this should be easy. Simply increase/move the size, you can do it with the graphical user interface. But you should make a backup of your important files before you do it. A backup is always useful.

Comment: @MikroPower Thank you very much will try it tonight. I always have a clone copy to External HDD.