# How to find Ubuntu specific partition in Files app and merge them with another partition?

Tags: partitioning, files, gparted, disk, disk-usage

I have 2 partitions like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMG4Q.png). I want to merge nvme0n1p7 and nvme0n1p9 with no deleting or losing of my data. Also, I want to see what files in 'Files' app for nvme0n1p7 partition since it uses a large amount of space. If i try to search, I just find the other partition size (20.28 GiB) when I check the 'home' properties.

Comment: You can install ncdu which is a bit easier to use, or just use du to see sizes of files & folders. Similar to this except use /home instead of / : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find Ubuntu specific partition in Files app. The Files app shows the entire file structure. In that file structure, the contents of mounted file systems, that reside on different partitions, will appears as just another part of the file system.

To find partitions, you can use the `lsblk` command. That command shows all existing drives, the partitions on these drives, and where the file system on these partitions is eventually mounted within the file structure.

So, for example, run `lsblk`, and find the entry `nvme0n1`, which is the drive designation. Then lines will connect to the different partitions. Look at `nvme0n1p7` and, under mount point, see the directory where that partition is mounted. Go to that directory with Files, and you will see the files on that partition.

Merging and deleting partitions without loosing the data that is on these partitions is not possible. You can only delete one partition to enlarge another. So at the very least, data on one of the partitions will be deleted.

In your specific case, you could enlarge the `p7` partition, i.e., preserve the operating system. However, to do that, you will need to delete the swap partition `p8` and the `/home` partition, `p9`. Once that is done, `p7` can be expanded to fill the remaining space, after which the contents of `/home` can be restored from a backup and instead of the swap partition, a swap file could be created.

These operations are rather technical and require a good understanding of partitions, mount points, etc. If you are uncomfortable with that, prefer to back up your personal data, delete all partitions `p7`, `p8` and `p9` and perform a default fresh install of Ubuntu in that free space using the installation USB or DVD, which is much easier to do, much more foolproof and which will hardly take more time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have reinstalled Ubuntu and luckily nothing wrong happened. Fyi, I deleted partitions p7, p8, and p9, also partition 6 because I don't know what is that partitions purpose. However, there seems to be no problem in the boot process and so on

Comment: Please "accept" the answer if it helped you: click the checkmark next to the question. This shows others there is at least one  usefull answer here, and is a sign of appreciation.

Comment: Thank you for the information